# SQL Join on the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Table T
P_ID | Name | Status
1      ABC    Ordered
1      ABC    Processing
1      ABC    Imported
2      PQR    Ordered
2      PQR    Failed
3      LMN    Ordered
```

Expected Result

```
Table T
P_ID | Name | Status
2      PQR    Ordered
2      PQR    Failed 
3      LMN    Ordered
```

I am not getting the correct result with the following query. I want to find all the records that have status Ordered but do not have the status "Imported".

```
select c1.P_ID,c1.Name,c2.Status
from T c1, T c2
where c1.P_ID = c2.P_ID
c1.Status="Ordered" and c2.status != "Imported"
```

Using Oracle 11g database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select c1.P_ID, c1.Name, c1.Status
from T c1
where c1.Status = 'Ordered' and 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM T c2
                  WHERE c1.P_ID = c2.P_ID and c2.status = 'Imported'
                 );
```

Comment: @user3384231 . . . The better version (well, now that I fixed the string delimiters).

Comment: @Luuk thanks. Can you please explain why do you have "SELECT 1"? whats the purpose of it?

Comment: The 1 is just a value returned bu the subquery, it does not mean anything, it just needs to exists as output for that subquery.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code:

```
select c1.P_ID,c1.Name,c1.Status
  from T c1
 where exists (select 1
                 from T
                where P_ID = c1.P_ID
                  and Status="Ordered"
                  and rownum = 1)
   and not exists (select 1
                     from T
                    where P_ID = c1.P_ID
                      and Status="Imported"
                      and rownum = 1)
```

Comment: thanks. Upvoted. Can you explain why do we need to use "rownum" in your approach?

Comment: . . . What is `rownum` ? Is that really necessary ?

Comment: @user3384231 `rownum` is here for the performance purposes. without it, the query would run as long as it takes to search through the whole table, while with `and rownum = 1` the query will stop searching after it finds the first row that fulfills the condition. In this very instance it's enough to fetch one such record - the only thing that matters is that it exists. For smaller tables the difference in running time will not be noticeable but it's always a good practice to include it because it has no downside when you use it in `exists` or `not exists` in such a fashion.

Comment: @user3384231 the difference between my answer and that from Luuk is that Luuks answer won't return you any rows that contain any status other than 'Ordered'. In your expected results you stated you wanted to see all rows from all orders that have status "Ordered" but do not have the status "Imported" - because of that I used `exists` instead of `where c1.Status = 'Ordered'` - so that you get all such rows returned and not only those with status "Ordered". See what fits you best.

Comment: @GoranKutlaca yes your correct. I should have clarified in my question. Actually, I will be running this report only when I have status as "Ordered". so it works fine if we hard code the status with c1.status= 'Ordered'